# Extracting image src based on attribute with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html-parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to get a HTML page from IMDb, and I would like to extract the poster image from the page. I've got the image based on one of the attributes, but  I don't know how to extract the data inside it.

Here's my code:

```
url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt%s/' % (id)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
print("before FOR")
for src in soup.find(itemprop="image"): 
    print("inside FOR")
    print(link.get('src'))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're almost there - just a couple of mistakes. `soup.find()` gets the first element that matches, not a list, so you don't need to iterate over it. Once you have got the element, you can get its attributes (like `src`) using dictionary access. Here's a reworked version:

```
film_id = '0423409'
url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt%s/' % (film_id)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
link = soup.find(itemprop="image")
print(link["src"])
# output:
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg2ODMwNTY3NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzczNjEzMQ@@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_.jpg
```

I've changed `id` to `film_id`, because [`id()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#id) is a built-in function, and it's bad practice to mask those.

Answer (score 5):

I believe your example is very close. You need to use findAll() instead of find() and when you iterate, you switch from src to link. In the below example I switched it to `tag`

This code is working for me with BeautifulSoup4:

```
url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt%s/' % (id,)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
print "before FOR"
for tag in soup.findAll(itemprop="image"): 
    print "inside FOR"
    print(tag['src'])
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you are looking for the src of the image, for the extraction of it after that.

In the first place you need to find (using the inspector) in which position in the HTML is the image. For example, in my particle case that I was scrapping soccer team shields, I needed:

```
m_url = 'http://www.marca.com/futbol/primera/equipos.html'
client = uOpen(m_url) 
page = client.read()
client.close()

page_soup = BS(page, 'html.parser')

teams = page_soup.findAll('li', {'id': 'nombreEquipo'})
for team in teams:
  name = team.h2.text
  shield_url = team.img['src']
```

Then, you need to process the image. You have to options.

1st: using **numpy**:

```
def url_to_image(url):
    '''
    Función para extraer una imagen de una URL
    '''
    resp = uOpen(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype='uint8')
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return image
```

shield = url_to_image(shield_url)

2nd Using **scikit-image** library (that you will probably need to install):

```
shield = io.imread('http:' + shield_url)
```

**Note:** Just in this particular example I needed to add http: at the beggining.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full working example with [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho):

**Step 1** - import everything and download the html:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.request import urlretrieve as download
from gazpacho import Soup

id = 'tt5057054'
url = f"https://www.imdb.com/title/{id}"

soup = Soup.get(url)
```

**Step 2** - find the src url for the image asset:

```py
image = (soup
    .find("div", {"id": "title-overview"})
    .find("div", {"class": "poster"})
    .find("img")
    .attrs['src']
)
```

**Step 3** - save it to your machine:

```py
directory = "images"
Path(directory).mkdir(exist_ok=True)

extension = image.split('.')[-1]
download(image, f"{directory}/{id}.{extension}")
```