# How to extract image from content, with beautifulsoup or python or anything?

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

**Iam trying to extract image from content, with beautifulsoup or python or anything.**

I tried using **python goose** but I'm not getting much help for this so I'm thinking to switch my tool to achieve this job.

I'm using **wyswyg editor** named **django-ckeditor**.

users make content through this editor which is being saved as a content field in my Post model. To display that, all I had to do was `{{post.content}}` content users can post are image and text.

Now I want to display the image separately from the content. I want to thumbnail the image that's in content.

I used python goose to achieve this as I have some experience with this. I'm not sure why it's not working this time.

Here's my code

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(config_name='default')
    @property

    def thumbnail(self, content):
        g = Goose()
        thumbnail = g.extract(raw_html=self.content).top_image.src
        return thumbnail
```

in html file

```
<img src="{{ post.thumbnail }}" />
```

nothing shows up.

How do I extract images from the content?

Comment: Here is a link to get images from the website-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304532/extracting-image-src-based-on-attribute-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: @Dlucidone yeah but I'm not getting images from other site, i'm trying to extract images from content field