# How to webscrape images from Google News?

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm still a bit new to webscraping, trying to scrape the article images from a Google News page and display them in my Django template. I've been following along with the tutorial from towardsDataScience that can be found [here.](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-tutorial-on-scraping-images-from-the-web-using-beautifulsoup-206a7633e948) Right now I'm just trying to get the img html data from each article div just to check that I am able to pull the data. The format should look like this: `<img alt="A Light in the Attic" class="thumbnail" src="media/cache/2c/da/2cdad67c44b002e7ead0cc35693c0e8b.jpg"/>`
However at the moment my code is returning an empty dictionary which tells me that I am not targeting the image correctly. Any advice from those who are more experienced would be welcome.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import *
from django.db.models import Count
import requests, urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def index(request):
    URL = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=beyond+meat&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS898US898&sxsrf=ALeKk00IH9jp1Kz5-LSyi7FUB4rd6--_hw:1624935518812&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwicqIbD7LvxAhVWo54KHXgRA9oQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1536&bih=754'
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    headers = soup.find_all('div', class_='BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd')
    header_dict = []
    for h in headers:
        header_dict.append(h.text)
    image = soup.find_all('div', class_="qV9w7d")
    context= {
        "header_dict": header_dict,
        "example": image,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: What are you passing to the  `request` argument in your `index` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable JavaScript on the website, you'll see that the image class-name changes from `qV9w7d` to `EYOsld`. And The `requests` module doesn't support JavaScript.

So, instead of:

```
image = soup.find_all('div', class_="qV9w7d")
```

Use:

```
image = soup.find_all('img', class_="EYOsld")
```

---

**NOTICE**! the images (the `src`) attribute are in base64 encoding, since there's already an in-depth post on that, I'll include the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36439888/12349734).

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. That may actually explain some issues I was having with other projects - the JavaScript just needed to be disabled for me to grab the correct class-name.

Comment: @melandalin CLASS names are dynamic names within HTML as Google implementation! from day to day you will notice it's got changed!