# How do I retrieve images located in a table from a website with my Python Codes?

Tags: python, image, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the following Python codes running in my Jupyter notebook:

```
from lxml.html import parse
tree = parse('http://www.imdb.com/chart/top')
movies = tree.findall('.//table[@class="chart full-width"]//td[@class="titleColumn"]//a')

movies[0].text_content()
```

The above codes give me the following output:

```
'The Shawshank Redemption'
```

Basically, it is the content of the first row of the column named 'titleColumn' on that webpage. In that same table there is another column called 'posterColumn' which contains a thumbnail image.

Now I want my codes to retrieve those images and the output to also show that image.

Do I need to use another package to achieve this? Can the image be shown in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: There's a very similar question [using bautifulsoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304532/extracting-image-src-based-on-attribute-with-beautifulsoup).

Comment: Thanks. I missed that one. I'll have a look and see where it goes from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the associated images, you need to get the `posterColumn`. From this you can extract the `img src` entry and pull the jpg images. The file can then be saved based on the movie title, with care to remove any non-valid filename characters such as `:`:

```
from lxml.html import parse
import requests
import string

valid_chars = "-_.() " + string.ascii_letters + string.digits
tree = parse('http://www.imdb.com/chart/top')
movies = tree.findall('.//table[@class="chart full-width"]//td[@class="titleColumn"]//a')
posters = tree.findall('.//table[@class="chart full-width"]//td[@class="posterColumn"]//a')

for p, m in zip(posters, movies):
    for element, attribute, link, pos in p.iterlinks():
        if attribute == 'src':
            print "{:50} {}".format(m.text_content(), link)
            poster_jpg = requests.get(link, stream=True)
            valid_filename = ''.join(c for c in m.text_content() if c in valid_chars)

            with open('{}.jpg'.format(valid_filename), 'wb') as f_jpg:
                for chunk in poster_jpg:
                    f_jpg.write(chunk)
```

So currently you would see something starting as:

```
The Shawshank Redemption                           https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_UY67_CR0,0,45,67_AL_.jpg
The Godfather                                      https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZTRmNjQ1ZDYtNDgzMy00OGE0LWE4N2YtNTkzNWQ5ZDhlNGJmL2ltYWdlL2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjU0OTQ0OTY@._V1_UY67_CR1,0,45,67_AL_.jpg
The Godfather: Part II                             https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjZiNzIxNTQtNDc5Zi00YWY1LThkMTctMDgzYjY4YjI1YmQyL2ltYWdlL2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjU0OTQ0OTY@._V1_UY67_CR1,0,45,67_AL_.jpg
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your time!